# Seleccionar registros de una tabla filtrando por término de búsqueda

Tags: php, sql

Realizo un formulario en donde busca por `ID` mis registros en mi tabla "reloj" (lo cual no tengo problema en la búsqueda). Con los siguientes campos, el campo `id` es mi `PK` e `id_Control` que hace referencia al N° de trabajador:

```
id
id_Control
fecha
hora
```

Lo que pretendo que realice, es que cuando quiero buscar un registro solo, que me aparezca el que yo busco. Ya que si por ejemplo quiero buscar el `id_Control` = 2, me busca todos los registros que contienen el número que yo ingresé en la búsqueda, un 2 en el `id_Control`.

```html
<?php
include('conexion.php');

$dato = $_POST['dato'];

//EJECUTAMOS LA CONSULTA DE BUSQUEDA

$registro = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reloj WHERE id_Control LIKE '%$dato%'  ORDER BY id ASC");

//CREAMOS NUESTRA VISTA Y LA DEVOLVEMOS AL AJAX

echo '<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
         <tr>
             <th width="300">No. De Control</th>
                <th width="200">Fecha</th>
                <th width="150">Hora</th>
            </tr>';
if(mysql_num_rows($registro)>0){
 while($registro2 = mysql_fetch_array($registro)){
  echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$registro2['id_Control'].'</td>
    <td>'.$registro2['fecha'].'</td>
    <td>'.$registro2['hora'].'</td>
    
    </tr>';
 }
}else{
 echo '<tr>
    <td colspan="6">No se encontraron resultados</td>
   </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: pero si tu id es único es decir priamry key cuando hagas la búsqueda no tendría por que mostrarte mas de un registro

Comment: No, de echo no es PK, tengo otro campo que se llama id ya que es una tabla donde se almacenan  temporalmente valores de un excel.csv, mi campo id_Control se refiere al no. de Control de empleado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en:

```
$registro = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reloj WHERE id_Control LIKE '%$dato%'  ORDER BY id ASC");
```

estas utilizando LIKE y los comodines % de SQL, por lo que te busca cualquier registro que contenga el patrón. Tienes que modificarlo por:

```
$registro = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reloj WHERE id_Control = '$dato'  ORDER BY id ASC");
```

Comment: Gracia spor la pronta respuesta, pero ya modifique lo que mencionas y aun sigue buscando los registros parecidos

Comment: Sí, disculpa, tienes que quitar el LIKE también, acabo de editarlo.

Comment: Aun me sigue buscando los parecidos, no entiendo el porque no respeta el select

Comment: Has probado a ejecutar el mismo query en la consola?

Comment: Si, la linea que me mencionaste y no me regresa ningun valor

Comment: Seguramente, $dato esté vacio y por eso te encuentra todos los registros. Introduce en la consola (cambia el '5' por un valor válido de tus registros): SELECT * FROM reloj WHERE id_Control = '5'  ORDER BY id ASC.

Comment: Haciendo lo que me indicas (colocar un numero de mis registros) si me los muestra.

Comment: Entonces el problema está en que $_POST['dato'] no recibe el campo del formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba concatenando la variable `$datos`, ya que en la consulta te esta leyendo esto:`'%$dato%'` como un string.

Modificalo de esta forma:

```
'%".$dato."%'
```

Por otro lado no veo la conexion declarada en la consulta, colocalo al final asi:

```
$registro = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reloj WHERE id_Control LIKE '%".$dato."%'  ORDER BY id ASC", $conexion);
```